# How to cleanly exit ruby in vimscript

Tags: ruby, vim

#### TLDR

Given a vim command like:

```
nnoremap <leader>x :ruby puts 'foo'; exit 0; puts 'bar'<CR>
```

What could I replace `exit 0` with to make this command exit cleanly without printing `'bar'`?

#### Longer version

Say I have a ruby script in my vimconfig.  For clarity I'll wrap it in a function, but that's not really necessary:

```
function! RubyTest()
ruby << EOF
  some_condition = true
  puts "aaa"
  return if some_condition
  puts "bbb"
EOF
endfunction
```

I want to, depending on some condition, exit this ruby code early so `puts "bbb"` doesn't get executed.

Now, I *could* just wrap the whole thing in a conditional:

```
  some_condition = true
  puts "aaa"
  unless some_condition
    puts "bbb"
  end
```

But this sucks if `puts "bbb"` is actually dozens of lines.  It's even worse if, instead of this toy example, I have a number of conditionals that would end up extremely nested and unreadable.

So, what I'd really like to do is:

```
some_condition = true
puts "aaa"
return if some_condition
puts "bbb"
```

However, `return` outputs an error:

```
Error detected while processing function RubyTest:
line    6:
LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

So does `exit`(`SystemExit: exit`), `next` (`SyntaxError: eval:3: Can't escape from eval with next`), and `break` (`SyntaxError: eval:3: Can't escape from eval with break`).

My best workaround is to wrap the entire content of the ruby script in a function, immediately execute that function, and then just `return` from within it as necessary.  That seems silly, though — surely there's some way to just cleanly exit from whatever weird context Vim is executing this ruby in, right?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because there is nothing to return *from*. `return` is intended to break out of the enclosing method, but in your example there is no method.

A possible fix is to create an enclosing method:

```
function! RubyTest()
ruby << EOF
 def my_method
  some_condition = true
  puts "aaa"
  return if some_condition
  puts "bbb"
 end
 my_method
EOF
endfunction
```

*Edit* Completely missed that you already suggested this solution yourself and was looking for alternatives. I can't offer any, or at least none that are any shorter or cleaner than the above. I'll delete this answer if you want.

Comment: Yes, I suggested that as the best workaround I had in the original question.  I was kinda looking for anything else.  Were this a normal ruby script, I could just do `exit`, but of course that doesn't work either because vim seems to catch the SystemExit exception and display it as an error.  So back to the original question: is there any way to exit early from the ruby script without introducing an additional level of nesting?

Comment: Possibly less verbose than `def my_method; ... return; ... end; my_method` might be `1.times do ... break ... end`. It's still a hack, but a shorter one.

Comment: @Fishtoaster I completely missed that bit of your question, sorry. Will try and look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: @Fishtoaster have you tried rescuing the `SystemExit` ? seems dirty to me but it should work in this case

Comment: Not a terrible idea- I suppose it'd work.  Could really throw any exception and catch it to get the same behavior.   Although I don't know if that buys me anything that wrapping the whole content in a function doesn't.